# Android - Listen to a disabled button

Tags: android, button, actionlistener

How can I respond to an event based on clicking a disabled `Button`.
I have a requirement that I have to present `Dialog`, when a disabled `Button` is clicked but the listener I have assigned does not fire even when I `setClickable(false)`

Am an android noob, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A disabled button cannot listen to any event, but you can customize your own button by extending `Button` class to make your own definition of disabling

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer, it isn't particularly useful. :-(

Answer (score 62):

You can for example use `#setActivated()` method instead. Disabling a view will ignore all events.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated(boolean).
Then you can customize text and background styles with `android:state_activate` attribute if you need:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="false"
      android:color="@color/a_color" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
      android:color="@color/another_color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: That's a pretty good alternative. Should be higher up, or even the accepted answer, imho.

Answer (score 8):

You can override onTouchEvent and create a listener like this :

```
class MyButton @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.materialButtonStyle) : MaterialButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var onDisableClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (!isEnabled && event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            onDisableClickListener?.onClick(this)
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    fun setOnDisableClickListener(l: OnClickListener?) {
        onDisableClickListener = l
    }
}
```

In your activity :

```
button.setOnDisableClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this), "The button is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
button.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this), "The button is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of disabling it, keep it enabled but use a flag to control your "inner state"

Comment: Could you (or someone) expand on this please?

Comment: no need to add a new flag when you can use buttons very own setActivated() method and then check with isActivated()

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using a flag to keep my button's state.

```
private boolean isMyButtonEnabled = false;

public void onMyButtonClick(View v) {
   if(isMyButtonEnabled){
      ..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add `android:allowClickWhenDisabled` attribute to your button in xml like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:allowClickWhenDisabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Please note that this is only available for API >= 31: https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/view/View#setAllowClickWhenDisabled(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

I looked for it but got nothing to listen the EditText block. So I find another way to activate it. If there is a near button or area that you already listen, you can enable `SetOnLongClickListener` to activate the block. It will be a secret but you can tell the users.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editText.setEnabled(true)
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to tackle this by using the `selected` state, which is generally available for use in widgets, and can be used in state list drawables. A simple search for usage of `isSelected` turns up results in ListView, GridView, TextView and TabLayout. And the documentation states

> Views are typically
>        * selected in the context of an AdapterView like ListView or GridView;
>        * the selected view is the view that is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use activated state to enable or disable button . It is clickable or as someone point use selected or checked state. Each of these state has a different meaning so use it carefully

Answer (score 0):

create in res/color/color_state.xml

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:color="#767C7F" android:state_activated="true" />
     <item android:color="#CBCBCB" android:state_activated="false" />
     <item android:color="#CBCBCB" />
  </selector>
```

set textColor by:

```
   android:textColor="@color/color_state"
```

set event click to change state color:

```
   binding.format1.setOnClickListener {
        binding.format1.isActivated = true
        binding.format2.isActivated = false
        binding.format3.isActivated = false
    }
```